# Generator does not use JDK8+ Optional if configured accordingly

Tags: spring-boot, openapi, openapi-generator, openapi-generator-maven-plugin

Currently I'm using an OpenAPI model (3.0.2) defining some end point with data furthermore I have defined in the open API model something like this:

```
 XYZ:
   type: object
   properties:
     id:
       type: string
       nullable: true
```

The issue is now that based on the openapi-generator-maven-plugin (version 6.4.0) the configuration looks like this

- Usage Spring Boot 3.0.2
- JDK17

```
<plugins>
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.openapitools</groupId>
    <artifactId>openapi-generator-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>6.4.0</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <goals>
          <goal>generate</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
          <inputSpec>${project.basedir}/xyz.yaml</inputSpec>
          <generatorName>spring</generatorName>
          <generateApiTests>false</generateApiTests>
          <generateModelTests>false</generateModelTests>
          <generateModels>true</generateModels>
          <generateApiDocumentation>false</generateApiDocumentation>
          <generateApis>false</generateApis>
          <configOptions>
            <skipDefaultInterface>true</skipDefaultInterface>
            <useSwaggerUI>false</useSwaggerUI>
            <apiPackage>package.api</apiPackage>
            <modelPackage>package.model</modelPackage>
            <library>spring-boot</library>
            <requestMappingMode>none</requestMappingMode>
            <documentationProvider>none</documentationProvider>
            <useJakartaEe>true</useJakartaEe>
            <useOptional>true</useOptional>
            <useSpringBoot3>true</useSpringBoot3>
            <useSpringController>false</useSpringController>
            <hideGenerationTimestamp>true</hideGenerationTimestamp>
            <openApiNullable>false</openApiNullable>
            <delegatePattern>false</delegatePattern>
            <interfaceOnly>false</interfaceOnly>
          </configOptions>
        </configuration>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>      
</plugins>
```

Currently the problem is that the generator does not generate an `Optional` (of the JDK existing since JDK8) for the above id in the code....

```
private String id;

public String getId() {
  return id;
}
```

If I use the configuration like this instead:

```
<useOptional>false</useOptional>

<openApiNullable>true</openApiNullable>
```

This will produce the code like this:

```
@JsonProperty("id")
private JsonNullable<String> id = JsonNullable.undefined();

public JsonNullable<String> getId() {
  return id;
}
```

This will imply to use a supplemental dependency in the project `org.openapitools:jackson-databind-nullable` which just recreates the Optional code of the JDK8+ ...

Does someone has a hint what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The Optional isn't setup to be used in the pojo.  If you examine the `api.mustache` template, you will see the following line in the imports

```
{{#useOptional}}
import java.util.Optional;
{{/useOptional}}
```

This implies that the `useOptional` tag is available to all of our templates.  Additionally, further down in the `api.mustache` template, you can see the `{>optionalDataType}}` being used.  This tells the template to insert the `OptionalDataType` template at this point.  The `OptionalDataType.mustache` checks if `useOptional` is true, and if it is, then it wraps the `dataType` in an `Optional`.  If it is false, then it returns the dataType directly.

We can use this information to update the `pojo.mustache` to allow for Optional.

First, you will need to add the import to `model.mustache`.  That's easy enough.  Copy the above import to the `model.mustache`.  Done.

Second, update the `pojo.mustache` to allow for `useOptional`.  The updates need to take place in four locations.  The field declaration, the getter,
the setter, and the builder.

For the field declaration, there are two locations where the field is declared, one, if the field is a container, and one where it isn't.  The below code is for if it isn't a container, but the same change can be made for if it is as well.

add this between the `{{^useContainer}}{{/useContainer}}` tags:

```
  {{#useOptional}}
      private {{>optionalDataType}} {{name}};
  {{/useOptional}}
```

for the fluent setter getter, update the template with this

```
  {{#useOptional}}
      public {{classname}} {{name}}({{{datatypeWithEnum}}} {{name}}) {
          this.{{name}} = Optional.of({{name}});
      return this;
      }
  {{/useOptional}}
  {{^useOptional}}
  public {{classname}} {{name}}({{{datatypeWithEnum}}} {{name}}) {
    {{#openApiNullable}}
    this.{{name}} = {{#isNullable}}JsonNullable.of({{name}}){{/isNullable}}{{^isNullable}}{{name}}{{/isNullable}};
    {{/openApiNullable}}
    {{^openApiNullable}}
    this.{{name}} = {{name}};
    {{/openApiNullable}}
    return this;
  }
  {{/useOptional}}
```

For the getter, update as follows:

```
  {{#useOptional}}
  public {{>optionalDataType}} {{getter}}() {
    return {{name}};
  }
  {{/useOptional}}
  {{^useOptional}}
      public {{>nullableDataType}} {{getter}}() {
      return {{name}};
      }
  {{/useOptional}}
```

and for the setter, update with this

```
  {{#useOptional}}
  public void {{setter}}({{>optionalDataType}} {{name}}) {
    this.{{name}} = {{name}};
  }
  {{/useOptional}}
  {{^useOptional}}
  public void {{setter}}({{>nullableDataType}} {{name}}) {
    this.{{name}} = {{name}};
  }
  {{/useOptional}}
```

If you are making optional collections or other things, then you will need to update those to check `useOptional` as well, but this should get you started.

Also, this is customizable as you want.  You can have the setter just use the dataType and create an optional of the item, or you can have it as I have written it.  Same with the fluent setter.